# Bootstrap dropdown stop working after php die

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i have a script in which there are bootstrap dropdowns. The code for it is as follows:-

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown dropdown-user" style="font-size:15px;">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="icon-user"></i>&nbsp; <span><?php echo $name; ?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="caret"></i></a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right width-220">
            <li><a href="changepassword.php"><i class="icon-lock2"></i> Change Password</a></li>
            <li><a href="../logout.php"><i class="icon-switch2"></i> Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now i run a php script after a form is submitted in which i am checking whether a table is there in the database or not. If it is there it fethces it and if it is not there php script dies. The code for it is below:-

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
       $sql="SELECT * FROM table1";
       $results = $con->query($sql);
       if ($results === FALSE) {
       echo "<script> noty({text: 'No Data Found',layout: 'topRight',timeout: 3500,closeWith: ['click', 'hover'],type: 'error'});</script>";
       die();
      } else {
      ........
      }
```

Now whenever the php script dies the dropdowns stop working.

I am just starting to learn php so please let me know what I am doing wrong or if there is a better way of looking at this problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: it won't be there  because if php fails `span` won't be created

Comment: Where is the code to create a dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you included bootstrap js file at the end of your page.
So when PHP dies, The bootsrap will not be loaded to the page. If its the reason change die with something else or move bootstrap js file to header.

PS:Besides use die whenever something goes wrong is not the best idea to handle errors.

Comment: Thank you bringing the bootstrap.js to header worked. What could be better way other than die because if query fails i don't want the rest of the script to work.

Comment: Well. consider using a good architecture for php program. For instance in MVC you can load quite different page if data submited via form is not what you are looking for.

Comment: And if you are still in flat php level manipulate it via include or require.